# Basic Continuity issue.

Tags: calculus, continuity

F is differentiable .
We know that : Lim F(x^2) = F(0) when x^2 -> 0

How can we show in an easy way that :
Lim F(x^2) = F(0) when x->0

Can we derive this directly from continuity, no need to explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All there is to show is that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$ because you can compose limits. But that is a consequence of the continuity of the function $x\mapsto x^2$ at $0$, which can be proved very easily because $|x^2| \leq |x|$ when $|x|\leq 1$.